# error while executing the following commands

Tags: docker

When I run the following commands I am getting the below output:

1. `sudo docker run ubuntu /bin/echo hello world
   WARNING: WARNING: Local (127.0.0.1) DNS resolver found in resolv.conf and containers can't use it. Using default external servers : [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]`
2. And when I run `docker version`, the output is:

   `mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied[/var/lib/docker|a0f30ece] -job  initserver() = ERR (1)
   2014/03/03 21:49:51 initserver: mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied`

What is the problem?

My Problem solved by following :

Try modify the /etc/default/docker file, un-comment the OPTS line:

6 # Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.

7 #DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8"

Comment: 1: You have a local dns server running, which is currently not supported by Docker. It thus falls back to the google servers.  2. Is the server properly started with sudo? It should create the correct folders.

Comment: 1. I also **sometimes** see that error even though I have no local DNS server running

Comment: If you solved it then please add the answer yourself and mark it as accepted, so people can quickly see it has been resolved.

Comment: This seems to be the related issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/541